# SQL to Hibernate Query Language (HQL) - missing IN

Tags: java, sql, hql

Desired SQL statement to convert

```
select * from tableA where columnA is not null 
order by cast(columnA as int), columnB
union all
select * from app_data_program where columnA is null order by columnB
```

My HQL attempt:

```
From TableA a where a.columnA is not null 
order by cast(a.columnA as int), a.columnB 
union all TableA b where b.columnA is not null order by b.columnB
```

When I converted the HQL to SQL to test as a result, i get the following:

```
SQL Error: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

Comment: You have a "?" in your query where a parameter should go.  Are you setting that parameter before trying to execute your statement?

Comment: i remvoed it to make the case easier. thanks

Comment: What DB are you using?  Googling that error looks like it is some version of Oracle.  (Google also gives back a bunch of links that might be worth looking into.)

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257757/how-to-execute-query-with-union-in-hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HQL doesn't allow use UNION ALL sql construct.

You must execute two different queries and then you can merge the results of them.

So you'll have:

First query:

```
From TableA a where a.columnA is not null 
order by cast(a.columnA as int), a.columnB
```

Second query:

```
TableA b where b.columnA is not null order by b.columnB
```

Comment: wont the merging create duplicate results?

Comment: Your query use UNION ALL (not discard duplicated). You can discard duplicated in a Java loop