# How to perform an insert with a select statement to put in multiple rows with HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

Need to know how to do an insert with HQL with a select and that select contains a union. Here's my test case

```
create table simple_author (
id bigint generated by default as identity,
first_name varchar(255),
last_name varchar(255),
primary key (id))

@Entity
public class SimpleAuthor {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;}
```

Assume the requirement is to insert 2 authors and if one fails for whatever reason the other is not persisted in the database.

Using just SQL and if Oracle or H2 I can do
Insert into simple_author(first_name, last_name) select ‘bob’,’smith’ from dual union select ‘frank’, ‘brown’ from dual

Or if using SQL Server:
Insert into simple_author(first_name, last_name) select ‘bob’,’smith’ union select ‘frank’, ‘brown’

Assume Bob Smith and Frank Brown are supplied by a user entering data in a UI.

Looking at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-insert
Seems to support a simple case. 
Seems there are a couple of issues:
Doing a union and the list of values to be added in this case bob smith and frank brown
For the union have tried a couple of solutions as seen in threads

[Hibernate Union alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives)

and

[How to execute query with union in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257757/how-to-execute-query-with-union-in-hibernate)

at best they only seem to get close to what is required.
So the question is How to write:
Insert into simple_author(first_name, last_name) select ‘bob’,’smith’ from dual union select ‘frank’, ‘brown’ from dual
In hsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately HQL/JPQL do not support this. Such things can be done with native query or techs like [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/INSERT), which does native query under the covers.

Comment: Yea .. that is my conclusion as well.

Answer (score 0):

at least for me I was using Spring and at the time of writing did not known within a DAO that Spring using the @Transactional annotation will manage the commit. Found out the entity manager will commit or rollback all rows based on if an exception occurs therefore I can reach the goal of an "all or nothing" being committed. So in my case the code is:

```
  // if an exception occurs then the transaction is rolled back there is not any
  // special code required.
  public List<SimpleAuthor> insertSimpleAuthors(List<SimpleAuthor> simpleAuthors) {   
   // try {
      //em.getTransaction().begin();
      for (SimpleAuthor entity : simpleAuthors) {
        em.persist(entity);     
      }
      //em.flush();
//    } catch (Exception ex) {
//      em.getTransaction().rollback();
//      throw ex;
//    }
    for (int i = 0; i < simpleAuthors.size(); i++) {
      //SimpleAuthor entity : simpleAuthors) {
      simpleAuthors.set(i, 
      em.createQuery("from SimpleAuthor where firstName = :firstName and lastName = :lastName",SimpleAuthor.class)
       .setParameter("firstName", simpleAuthors.get(i).getFirstName())
       .setParameter("lastName", simpleAuthors.get(i).getLastName())
       .getSingleResult()
       );
    }
    return simpleAuthors;
  }
```